# "IF NOT EXISTS" Unrecognized when I init hive-metastore

Tags: hive, ambari, hive-metastore

when I install hive 4.0.0 on ambari and init hive metatore，I got this error:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS SYS
FAILED: SemanticException Unrecognized token in CREATE DATABASE statement
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Unrecognized token in CREATE DATABASE statement (state=42000,code=40000)
Closing: 0: jdbc:hive2://?hive.conf.restricted.list=;hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist=.*;hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist.append=.*;hive.security.authorization.enabled=false;hive.metastore.uris=;hive.security.authorization.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdConfOnlyAuthorizerFactory;hive.support.concurrency=false;hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DummyTxnManager;hive.metastore.rawstore.impl=org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent!
Underlying cause: java.io.IOException : Schema script failed, errorcode 2
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent!
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.tools.schematool.SchemaToolTaskInit.execute(SchemaToolTaskInit.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.tools.schematool.MetastoreSchemaTool.run(MetastoreSchemaTool.java:480)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.schematool.HiveSchemaTool.main(HiveSchemaTool.java:143)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Schema script failed, errorcode 2
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.schematool.HiveSchemaTool.execSql(HiveSchemaTool.java:110)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.schematool.HiveSchemaTool.execSql(HiveSchemaTool.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.tools.schematool.SchemaToolTaskInit.execute(SchemaToolTaskInit.java:62)
    ... 8 more
*** schemaTool failed ***
```

that very confused me, how it happend and does anyone have any idea